# For any $\beta>0$, there is a constant $c>0$ such that $\left\|(1-\Delta)^{\frac{\beta}{2}} f\right\|_{\infty} \leq c\|f\|_{C_b^\beta}$

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, harmonic-analysis, bessel-potential

For any $n \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$, let $C_b^n\left(\mathbb{R}^d\right)$ be the class of real functions $f$ on $\mathbb{R}^d$ with continuous derivatives $\left\{\nabla^i f\right\}_{0 \leq i \leq n}$ such that
$$
\|f\|_{C_b^n}:=\sum_{i=0}^n\left\|\nabla^i f\right\|_{\infty}<\infty .
$$

For any $n \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$and $\alpha \in(0,1)$, let $C_b^{n+\alpha}\left(\mathbb{R}^d\right)$ be the space of functions $f \in C_b^n\left(\mathbb{R}^d\right)$ such that
$$
\|f\|_{C_b^{n+\alpha}}:=\|f\|_{C_b^n}+\sup _{x \neq y} \frac{\left|\nabla^n f(x)-\nabla^n f(y)\right|}{|x-y|^\alpha}<\infty .
$$

At the end of page 582 of [this](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0022039623002255) paper, the author said that

> The next lemma contains two classical estimates on the operator $1-\Delta$ and the heat semigroup $P_t=\mathrm{e}^{t \Delta}$.
>
> **Lemma 5.2.**
>
> (1) For any $\beta>0$, there exists a constant $c>0$ such that
> $$
> \left\|(1-\Delta)^{\frac{\beta}{2}} f\right\|_{\infty} \leq c\|f\|_{C_b^\beta} . \tag{$*$} \label{*}
> $$
>
> (2) For any $\alpha, \beta, k \geq 0$, there exists a constant $c>0$ such that
> $$
> \left\|(1-\Delta)^{-k} P_t f\right\|_{C_b^{\alpha+\beta}} \leq c t^{-\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}-k\right)^{+}}\|f\|_{C_b^\beta}, \quad t>0 .
> $$

I would like to use (\ref{*}) of **Lemma 5.2**(1) in my paper. Could you elaborate on the references that contain this result so that I can cite it?

Thank you so much for your help!